# Agrupar por meses en python

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, group-by, pycharm

Tengo una tabla con una columna "DateAndTime" (formato año-mes-día-hora-minuto-segundo) y otra columna "Status", en esta columna tengo 3 valores posibles: Hiper, Hipo, Okey. Este data frame se llama "dataOfStatusTimings"

```
          DateAndTime Status Duration   
0 2019-01-09 00:07:00  Hiper 04:30:00 
1 2019-01-09 04:37:00   Okey 06:15:00  
2 2019-01-09 10:52:00  Hiper 01:15:00  
3 2019-01-09 12:07:00   Okey 00:30:00  
4 2019-01-09 12:37:00   Hipo 01:00:00
```

**Me gustaría agrupar la tabla de tal forma que me diga cuántos Hiper, Hipo y Okey, hay por mes-año.**

**Lo he conseguido agrupar pero por día, no por mes.**

Para ello, primero he puesto el "DateAndTime" en dos columnas diferentes "Date" y "Time":

```
dataOfStatusTimings['Date']=[d.date() for d in dataOfStatusTimings['DateAndTime']]
dataOfStatusTimings['Time']=[d.time() for d in dataOfStatusTimings['DateAndTime']]
```

Obteniendo:

```
         DateAndTime Status Duration        Date      Time
0 2019-01-09 00:07:00  Hiper 04:30:00  2019-01-09  00:07:00
1 2019-01-09 04:37:00   Okey 06:15:00  2019-01-09  04:37:00
2 2019-01-09 10:52:00  Hiper 01:15:00  2019-01-09  10:52:00
3 2019-01-09 12:07:00   Okey 00:30:00  2019-01-09  12:07:00
4 2019-01-09 12:37:00   Hipo 01:00:00  2019-01-09  12:37:00
```

Y luego he agrupado por el campo "Date" y "Status":

```
dataOfStatusCounting = dataOfStatusTimings.groupby(['Date', 'Status']).agg({'Status': ['count']}).unstack('Status').fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Obteniendo:

```
     Date Status          
                    count          
Status              Hiper Hipo Okey
0       2019-01-09    4.0  2.0  5.0
1       2019-01-10    4.0  3.0  6.0
2       2019-01-11    4.0  3.0  6.0
3       2019-01-12    2.0  2.0  4.0
4       2019-02-09    3.0  2.0  5.0
```

**¿Cómo podría agruparla por mes-año?** De manera que no se agrupen juntos los datos de enero de 2018 y enero 2019, si no que estén por un lado enero 2018 y por otro enero 2019.

Ya se que puedo obtener el año y el mes por separado de la siguiente forma:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(dataOfStatusTimings['Date']).year
```

Obteniendo:

```
Int64Index([2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,
            ...
            2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019],
           dtype='int64', name='Date', length=1469)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otra posibilidad, más compacta y quizás más legible, pero sobre todo más flexible, sería la siguiente:

Partimos del siguiente dataframe de ejemplo:

```
>>> df
           DateAndTime Status  Duration
0  2019-01-09 00:07:00  Hiper  04:30:00
1  2019-01-09 04:37:00   Okey  06:15:00
2  2019-01-09 10:52:00  Hiper  01:15:00
3  2019-01-09 12:07:00   Okey  00:30:00
4  2019-01-09 12:37:00   Hipo  01:00:00
```

Nos aseguramos de que la columna con la fecha y hora sea de tipo `datetime`:

```
>>> df.DateAndTime = pd.to_datetime(df.DateAndTime)
```

Utilizando `crosstab`, se crean automáticamente nuevas columnas "Hiper", "Hipo", "Okey" con un 1 o un 0 según corresponda en cada fila:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df.DateAndTime, df.Status)
Status               Hiper  Hipo  Okey
DateAndTime                           
2019-01-09 00:07:00      1     0     0
2019-01-09 04:37:00      0     0     1
2019-01-09 10:52:00      1     0     0
2019-01-09 12:07:00      0     0     1
2019-01-09 12:37:00      0     1     0
```

Y ahora ya puedes hacer `.resample()` sobre el índice, para juntar todas las muestras por cualquier intervalo temporal que desees. En tu caso decías por meses, entonces puedes hacer `.resample("M").sum()`:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df.DateAndTime, df.Status).resample("M").sum()
Status       Hiper  Hipo  Okey
DateAndTime                   
2019-01-31       2     1     2
```

Este ejemplo con tan pocos datos queda muy "soso", pero la gracia es que puedes resamplear por cualquier otro intervalo. Por ejemplo, cada 12 horas:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(df.DateAndTime, df.Status).resample("12H").sum()
Status               Hiper  Hipo  Okey
DateAndTime                           
2019-01-09 00:00:00      2     0     1
2019-01-09 12:00:00      0     1     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Acabo de descubrir cómo puedo agruparlo. Primero añado 2 columnas: año y mes, de la siguiente forma.

```
A = dataOfStatusTimings
    A['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dataOfStatusTimings['DateAndTime']).month
    A['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dataOfStatusTimings['DateAndTime']).year
```

Siendo A:

```
     DateAndTime Status Duration        Date      Time  Month  Year
0 2019-01-09 00:07:00  Hiper 04:30:00  2019-01-09  00:07:00      1  2019
1 2019-01-09 04:37:00   Okey 06:15:00  2019-01-09  04:37:00      1  2019
2 2019-01-09 10:52:00  Hiper 01:15:00  2019-01-09  10:52:00      1  2019
3 2019-01-09 12:07:00   Okey 00:30:00  2019-01-09  12:07:00      1  2019
4 2019-01-09 12:37:00   Hipo 01:00:00  2019-01-09  12:37:00      1  2019
```

Y luego agrupo de esta manera:

```
    B = A.groupby(['Month', 'Year', 'Status']).agg({'Status': ['count']}).unstack('Status').fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Llegando a lo que quería:

```
 Month  Year Status          
                    count          
Status              Hiper Hipo Okey
0          1  2019     14   10   21
1          2  2019     11    7   18
2          3  2019     13   12   25
3          4  2019     14    9   24
4          5  2019     12   11   26
```

Comment: no olvides marcar como aceptada tu respuestas, claro esto lo tendras que hacer  24 horas despues de haber respondido